# Iterate by level over right most element of a heap

Tags: c++

Is there a way I can create a for loop such that, given any starting location the loop will subsequently iterate through the right-most element of each level? Given some heap:

[image]

If you were inside a `make_heap` function, you may start at `(n-2)/2)` which would be the node denoted by the red twelve.

Now, given some start location `(n-2)/2`, is it possible to iterate such that the subsequent values of the loop will be `6 -> 2 -> 0` (array location of the right most elements above the initial level, which is the red number minus one) which correspond to `14 -> 24 -> 25`.

---

My initial implementation looks like

```cpp
using std::size_t;

size_t n = last - first; // size of heap
for(size_t start = (n-2)/2; 
    start > 0;
    start = (size_t)pow(2, (size_t)log2(start)-1))
{
    std::cout << start << std::endl;
}
```

My thinking was that start is equal to 2<sup>log<sub>2</sub>(start)-1</sup>, which means the previous level. 
However this only yields `11, 4, 2, 1` (add one for the corresponding node location in red). It in theory should be `11, 6, 2, 0`. Any ideas?

Comment: You seem to be having trouble with the off by one issues of thinking about both 1 based and 0 based indexing.  In 1 based indexing the level is `v=floor(log2(n))` so in zero based indexing that is `v=floor(log2(n+1))`.  Then the rightmost element of the next lower level in 1 based indexing is `n=pow(2,v)-1` so in zero based indexing it is  `n=pow(2,v)-2`

Comment: So combining the above two equations for zero based indexing would be `n=pow(2,floor(log2(n+1))-2;`  You can hide the 'floor` inside a cast to integer type as you seem to prefer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your indices are 1-based, it is straight forward to compute the parent and the child nodes of a node given its index `n`:

- you get the parent node using `n / 2`
- you get the left child node using `n * 2`
- you get the rigth child node using `n * 2 + 1`

Since arrays in C++ are 0-base you may need to strategically add/substract 1 to convert between node and array indices.

To get to the right children of the the parent nodes you'd keep the index `p` of the current parent node, replacing it using `p = p / 2` in each direction and access the node at `p * 2 + 1`. Of course, if `make_heap()` is anything like `std::make_heap()` it doesn't need to do anything like that. It merely needs to "bubble up" the new node while its parent is bigger the node.

Comment: the catch is that I don't need the right *child* of the parent node, I need the right *most child* of the level of the parent node. I've figured it out however and will post an answer shortly